# How to add a new array of objects to an object to make it nested and if newly added array already exists, add another object to that array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects *questions.json* which looks like

```
   "id": "2",
  "ques": "here is my second code ?",
  "quesBrief": "I can't seem to find it too.",
  "hashes": "#javascript , #goodlord",
  "author": "slowdeathv123",
  "dateTime": "2021-09-22 18:13:12",
  "date": "2021-09-22",
  "sortOrder": -99,
  "code": " - utlis (folder contains GO files)\n  ---sendMail.go \n--templates (folder)\n --- reset_code.html\n - main.go"
```

I want to add *answers array of objects* to it to make it a nested object and add more objects to *answers array* using a fetch/axios/async await request to make it like

```
"id": "2",
  "ques": "here is my second code ?",
  "quesBrief": "I can't seem to find it too.",
  "hashes": "#javascript , #goodlord",
  "author": "slowdeathv123",
  "dateTime": "2021-09-22 18:13:12",
  "date": "2021-09-22",
  "sortOrder": -99,
  "code": " - utlis (folder contains GO files)\n  ---sendMail.go \n--templates (folder)\n --- reset_code.html\n - main.go"
  "answers": [
    {
    "answerBrief": "Check under the bed",
    "answerCode": "no code sorry",
    "answerAuthor": "Sonya"
    },
    {
    "answerBrief": "Any other random solution",
    "answerCode": "no code sorry",
    "answerAuthor": "ABC"
    }
   ],
```

How to create a post request to add an array of objects inside an object while checking if the answers array already exists, if not create one and add objects to it?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: I am new to handling json data anyway I tried to use PUT req but it totally updated the data. Now I know I need to use POST req but how to use it to modify nested objects?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about PUT/POST requests. What are you actually trying to do. You should update your question to explain the actual issue.

Comment: I hope the question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense?

```
   let data = {
      "id": "2",
      "ques": "here is my second code ?",
      "quesBrief": "I can't seem to find it too.",
      "hashes": "#javascript , #goodlord",
      "author": "slowdeathv123",
      "dateTime": "2021-09-22 18:13:12",
      "date": "2021-09-22",
      "sortOrder": -99,
      "code": " - utlis (folder contains GO files)\n  ---sendMail.go \n--templates (folder)\n --- reset_code.html\n - main.go",
    };
      
    const newAnswer = {
      "answerBrief": "Check under the bed",
      "answerCode": "no code sorry",
      "answerAuthor": "Sonya"
    };
    
    const answers = [...data.answers || [], newAnswer];

    data = {
      ...data,
      answers
    }
```

If you need to add answers that comes after POST request:

```
fetch('your-api-url-to-add-answers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // data with answers i think? 
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(answersData => {
    const answers = [...data.answers || [], answeersData];
    data = {
      ...data,
      answers
    }
});
```

If you need to send data with updated answers:

```
  const answers = [...data.answers || [], answeersData];
  const payload = {
     ...data,
     answers
  }

fetch('your-api-url-to-add-answers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload) // data with answers i think? 
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(answersData => {});
```

But for a more accurate answer, provide a little more detail. What data needs to be sent in a post request, and what kind of response you receive from the server.

Comment: How to create a request to post/update the json file?

Comment: Sorry to tell you this but this won't work, if answers do not exists or it is empty by the time you spread it, it will break

Comment: Ok so how to create a post request to add objects to answers if it already exists?

Comment: @Ernesto it will work if answers do not exists or it is empty. Take a close look at this line: 
[...data.answers || [], newAnswer].